# getting category number without accessing category_flat

Tags: category, flat

On occasion our category_flat table isn't available.  This causes some areas of our codebase to break.  How can I get the category number of a given category without accessing this table?  Thx.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you have to get the category?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I just need another method to retrieve the category number.. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The category id is in `catalog_category_entity` but you need something to filter for it?!

The easiest way is to load it:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id)->getCategoryNumber()
```

But if you only need the number, there is a far better way I can't find at the moment. In magento exists a model (at least for products), which loads you the value of exactly one attribute by `entity_id`.

Comment: Okay if I had the category id already how would I get the category number (bypassing the flat table of course).

Comment: What is the category number?

Comment: an attribute who's attribute id is equivalent to 135.

Comment: updated answer..